# How to Debug a SIGTERM that Causes Abrupt Helidon Server Shutdown

Tags: java, exit, sigterm, shutdown-hook

A simple Java program catches `kill -SIGTERM` and starts the JVM shutdown hooks (i.e., `Runtime.addShutdownHook()`).  When the hooks complete, the JVM shuts down cleanly.

A simple Helidon server has a JVM shutdown hook to ensure the `CDI` shuts down cleanly.  Netty stops listening.  I have `@BeforeDestroyed`, `@Destroyed`, and JVM shutdown hooks that simply log a message.  The hooks log and complete.  The server and JVM shut down cleanly.

I have a much more complex Helidon server.  I have code that monitors for a special delete file.  When I create the delete file, the code detects the file and initiates the shutdown.  I see log messages from Netty, `@BeforeDestroyed`, `@Destroyed`, and the JVM shutdown hooks.  The server and JVM shut down cleanly.  The shutdown takes 1.011 seconds.

When I send `kill -SIGTERM` to the complex Helidon server, the server stops abruptly.  Netty does not shut down.  The hooks are not called.  The server exits within milliseconds.

How do I debug why the server exits abruptly?  What could cause the server to exit abruptly upon receiving a `SIGTERM`?

I can reproduce this problem on Windows (with Cygwin's kill) and Linux.

Comment: Well, it's not supposed to finish on a SIGTERM without running the shutdown hooks. Maybe there's something in the hooks that cause issues? Dunno if some native debugger might be useful to get further information, or look at OS logs to see if there's something about it.

Comment: @Kayaman  Agreed.  The SIGTERM tells the process to start the shutdown procedure.  Unfortunately, something kills the process instead of letting the shutdown procedure begin.  It's been a long time since I used a native debugger.  That seems daunting since I figure I would need to build a JVM.  I am not sure what Windows or Linux log file to look at.

Comment: What's the exit code of the complex server when stopped with SIGTERM?

Comment: You can run the complex server under the debugger and put a breakpoint in `Runtime.halt`, just in case something is calling that.

Comment: @tgdavies The exit code is 143. I put a breakpoint on Runtime.halt() and java.lang.Shutdown.halt(). Neither of them are hit.  I left the breakpoint there and ran another program.  Both breakpoints are hit.

Comment: I think you need to make sure that you are running them both in *exactly* the same way, and start to make one more like the other until you find out what's happening.